# Conditional Windows comments in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, compatibility

What's the canonical Windows/Not-windows conditional comment in Common Lisp?

```
#-win32 (non-windows-stuff) #+win32 (usually-some-horrific-hack)
```

seems to work correctly on SBCL and LispWorks (whether the underlying platform is 32 or 64 bit), but CCL only seems to understand

```
#-windows (non-windows-stuff) #+windows (usually-some-horrific-hack)
```

How do I dispatch on platform in a portable (across implementations) way? Is there a reference for standard comment flags somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no canonical element of `*features*` that works across all implementations. The [trivial-features project](https://github.com/trivial-features/trivial-features) normalizes features across platforms and implementations so, after loading trivial-features, you can use `#+windows` anywhere to mean Windows.

Answer (score 4):

`#+` and `#-` tests the presence of the symbol in the [*features*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_featur.htm#STfeaturesST) list. Try checking it's value on the repl of the implementations/platforms you're targeting to see if you can find something in common.

You can also use `#+(or windows win32)` to test for either of them.

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
#+(OR WIN32 WINDOWS MSWINDOWS) ...
```

Also

```
#+(and (not windows) (or win32 mswindows))(pushnew :windows *features*)
```

and then

```
#+windows ...
```